# How to access RStudio menu items from keyboard

Tags: macos, rstudio

On Linux `Alt+H` activates the Help dropdown menu in RStudio and other programs.

So `Alt+H U` can search for updates.

On Mac I was expecting `Cmd+?` to do something similar, based on this: https://superuser.com/questions/303525/what-is-the-shortcut-to-access-the-menubar-in-mac-os-x

Just tested that on my sister's Mac and it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts you mentioned are not related to RStudio, they are a feature from the system. What you are doing is accessing the menubar with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then hit one of the underlined shortcuts.

I guess you found the answer to your own question on that topic from SuperUser: it seems that it is not possible to achieve exactly the same behaviour.

You may also want to check this answer on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/50825/151764).

You can access a list of keyboard shortcuts [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts). You can also [customize](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206382178-Customizing-Keyboard-Shortcuts) them.

For example, for the Help menu, I guess the closer you can find in RStudio are the following:

- Show help for function at cursor <kbd>F1</kbd>
- Move focus to Help <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>